# How to pass #text in Twig

Tags: php, api, symfony, twig, silex

I have a problem with the Last.fm API & Twig. I have this array and want to get the image URL, so I put this into my Twig file:

```
{{ xxxx.image[0]['#text'] }}
```

This is my array:

```
   Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [name] => David Bowie
            [listeners] => 3091283
            [mbid] => 5441c29d-3602-4898-b1a1-b77fa23b8e50
            [url] => http://www.last.fm/music/David+Bowie
            [streamable] => 0
            [image] => Array
                (
                    [0] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [#text] => http://img2-ak.lst.fm/i/u/34s/937d62bb145040b9b709319c1e680037.png
                            [size] => small
                        )
```

But I have this Twig error:

> Impossible to access a key "#text" on an object of class "stdClass"

How can I fix this?

Comment: try `{{ xxxx.image[0].#text }}`

Comment: Thx, but i have already try but i have this error message : Unexpected character "#"

Comment: Than you need to change the name of the field manually I believe. That field name looks very, odd. And access normally with a dot.

Comment: Yes, the field name is bad. But this is the Last.fm API.. So i can't change it ! lol

Comment: Yes you can ;) but it's a pesky way of doing it. Try @Matteo's answer :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [TWIG attribute function](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/functions/attribute.html) as follow:

```
{{ attribute(xxxx.image[0], '#text') }}
```

Hope this help

Comment: Hi @NansThomas if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.